# combine/merge html table rows into one from mysql and php pivot table

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, pivot

I have a mysql table with a plain schedule:

```
    +-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
    | Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
    +-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
    | id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |      
    | identity    | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL              |
    | start       | datetime     | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
    | end         | datetime     | YES  | MUL | NULL              |    
    +-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

i have a php script:

```
$begin = new DateTime( $_SESSION['start'] );
$end = new DateTime( $_SESSION['end'] ); 
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

foreach ( $period as $dt )
  $massivequery[]= "case(date(start)) when '".$dt->format( "Y-m-d" )."' then hour(timediff(end,start)) end as '".$dt->format( "Y-m-d" )."'";

$view_start = $_SESSION['start'];
$view_end = $_SESSION['end'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"
select schedule.identity,".implode(',',$massivequery)." from schedule join names on schedule.id_code=names.id_code where schedule.away is null and schedule.errand is null and date(schedule.start) between '".$view_start."' and '".$view_end."'
");

echo "<table align='center' border='1'>";

$i = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    if ($i == 0) {
      $i++;
      echo "<tr>";
      foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        echo "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
      }
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $value) {
      echo "<td id='".$row['identity']."'>" . $value . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

The problem is that this gives me almost perfect table that I need. It's pivoted, all the table headings are correct but the problem is that it gives sa separate row for each day a person is on schedule. i would like the rows with the same id merged into one row. i do not mean colspan or rowspan.
The table i am getting

```
<table align="center" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr><th>identity</th>
<th>2017-03-20</th>
<th>2017-03-21</th>
<th>2017-03-22</th></tr>

<tr><td id="12345">12345</td>
<td id="12345">8</td>
<td id="12345"></td>
<td id="12345"></td></tr>

<tr><td id="12345">12345</td>
<td id="12345"></td>
<td id="12345">8</td>
<td id="12345"></td></tr>

<tr><td id="12345">12345</td>
<td id="12345"></td>
<td id="12345"></td>
<td id="12345">8</td></tr>

</tbody></table>
```

The table i would like to get instead

```
<table align="center" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr><th>identity</th>
<th>2017-03-20</th>
<th>2017-03-21</th>
<th>2017-03-22</th></tr>

<tr><td id="12345">12345</td>
<td id="12345">8</td>
<td id="12345">8</td>
<td id="12345">8</td></tr>

</tbody></table>
```

This here is just a simple example with simple data. i actually have ca 40-50 different identities and the usual length is 30 not 3 days. the query is dependant on another application so i have to be able to use session variables for stating the time period. that's why i cannot manually build up a proper mysql query (or atleast i do not know how).
once again, i'm pretty sure that there is some kind of super elegant and easy way to do this with jquery but i am failing to see how.

Comment: once again, simple elegant edit in mysql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to edit the mysql query for it to work. too simple.

i edited this (added group_concat() function with separator ' + '):

```
$massivequery[]= "group_concat(case(date(start)) when '".$dt->format( "Y-m-d" )."' then hour(timediff(end,start)) end SEPARATOR ' + ') as '".$dt->format( "Y-m-d" )."'";
```

and this ( added group by):

```
select schedule.identity,".implode(',',$massivequery)." from schedule join names on schedule.id_code=names.id_code where schedule.away is null and schedule.errand is null and date(schedule.start) between '".$view_start."' and '".$view_end."' group by schedule.identity
```

now i have a fully dynamic pivot table.